# Why does NDepend show CQL errors when run on the command line but not from the GUI?

Tags: static-analysis, ndepend, cqlinq

I've got this bit of CQL:

```
// <Name>A stateless class or structure might be turned into a static type</Name>
warnif count > 0 (from t in Application.Types where
  t.SizeOfInst ==0 &&

  // For accuracy, this constraint doesn't take
  // account of types that implement some interfaces.
  // and classes that have a base class and don't
  // derive directly from System.Object, or classes
  // that have sub-classes children.  
  t.NbInterfacesImplemented == 0 &&                           
  ((t.IsClass && t.DepthOfInheritance == 1   
            && t.NbChildren == 0)          
    || t.IsStructure) &&                   
  !t.IsStatic &&
  !t.DeriveFrom("System.Attribute") &&
  !t.IsAttributeClass &&
  !t.IsGeneric && t.Name!="Program" && !(t.IsGeneratedByCompiler || t.HasAttribute(@"NDepend.CQL.NDependIgnoreAttribute") || t.HasAttribute("System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute".AllowNoMatch()))
select new { t, t.SizeOfInst, t.NbInterfacesImplemented, 
             t.DepthOfInheritance, t.NbChildren }).Take(10)
  // this rule indicates stateless types that might 
  // eventually be turned into static classes.
  // See the definition of the SizeOfInst metric here 
  // http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#SizeOfInst
```

It's fine in the GUI, but I get this message in the output report when I run it from the command line:

```
1 query syntax error: Not a valid type name {"System.Attribute"}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Steven did my answer helped solving the issue you mentioned? If it is a bug in our product, we'd like to get it fixed, but so far we cannot repro it. Thanks

Comment: Hi @PatrickfromNDependteam.  Thanks for the answer (I upvoted when you posted), but I haven't had a chance to verify it yet.  When I do, I'll let you know.  Thanks for following up, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It must come from the fact that `mscorlib`, the assembly that contains `System.Attribute`, is not resolve at analysis time. Are you running GUI and command line versions on the same machine? To look at assembly resolving go to *NDepend Project Properties > Code to Analyze* and see from where `mscorlib` is resolved by unfolding the folder panel.